What is a basic characterization of relations among metaphor, analogy, and categorification/classification?
Continuing relation of metaphor, analogy, with symmetry my third question is what is the relation between metaphor/analogy with categorification/classification .Please provide examples .

If someone had read SURFACES AND ESSENCES by DOUGLAS HOFSTADTER

Categories (SEP) are essentially "buckets" that we use to associate common properties most natively to cognition in natural language. For instance, English, German, and French are all natural languages, which is to say that they possess the properties of natural languages. This would be in distinction to Python, JavaScript, and Java which are all artificial languages. Categorization is the notion of exercising philosophical judgement (here's Bretano's Theory of Judgement (SEP), for instance) for deciding which instances belong to which categories. In the language of set theory, we are talking about deciding which elements belong to which sets.
If we talk about which things do or do not exist as well as which categories to which they belong in our natural languages, then we are dealing with natural language ontology (SEP) which is preoccupied with two very important categories, real and unreal. This is one of the central tasks of metaphysics (SEP), in fact. Is the 2024 King of France bald, to borrow a classic example? The question of the membership of the category of baldness then becomes mired down in the question of whether or not said king is in the category of real. Of course, such a king is imaginary, and modern philosophers might be have to resort to a fictionalist account (SEP) of metaphysical explanation.
Similes and metaphors (SEP) and analogies (SEP) are cognitive processes to stretch category membership. When the great Robert Burns wrote "O my Luve is like a red, red rose, That’s newly sprung in June" he was employing metaphor since on a naive reading 'love' and 'red rose' are generally not seen as belong to similar categories. In the literal sense 'love' generally is equated to a variety of psychological states such as limerence. And a rose, taken literally, is a member of the flowering genus Rosa under modern cladistics. Love is taken as belonging to the mental category, whereas a flowers are taken to belong to the physical category. A rose, in this way, gains currency as a poetic symbol.
The primary difference between metaphors and analogies is simply one of linguistic structure. Since you've read Surface and Essences, you are acquainted with the idea that the brain/mind (what have you given your metaphysics) is essentially an engine that deals with these categories and judgements. Metaphors are brief attempts to move from a concrete to abstract category (rose-as-flower becomes rose-as-symbol-of-love), where as analogies and particular analogical reasoning, can be quite extended in terms of linguistic structure achieving up to multi-volume arguments to establish a categorical designation.
Lakoff and others have argued that such metaphors are actually rooted in the physiology of the brain and the lowest "levels" of the mind in the form of the conceptual metaphor. Thus, famously in Metaphors We Live By, Lakoff and Johnson argue that part of how we conceptualize love is by such metaphors. Love As a Journey. Love As a Contract. Love As a Duty. The notion of the conceptual metaphor among linguists and neurophysiologists is contentious, however.
Whatever the case, in line with Hofstadter and Sanders, we can see the preliminary philosophical arguments rooted in cognitive science (SEP) and the computational theory of mind (SEP) put judgment at the heart of creating and using categories in natural language. These sorts of questions, about how natural language does this, since Chomsky, has become more and more formalized, particularly with Montague's Grammar and his Theory of Semantics. Today, such questions about metaphor, analogy, categories, and ontology are an active field of research in a variety of fields, particularly natural language processing.

Sure. I'll try to get around to it in the next few days.
